# Pycharm no longer prompts me to open in "this window" or "new window"

Tags: pycharm

How do I re-enable this prompt?

It is something that I found quite useful and somehow managed to accidentally disable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyCharm can work with several projects in one window. Open your project, while another one is already opened. Then, depending on the option selected in the *Project Opening* section of the *System Settings* page of the *Settings/Preferences*, the following happens:

- If the *Open project in a new window* option is selected, the new project silently opens in a new window. The *Attach Project* option appears in the *File* menu.
- If the *Open projects in the same window option* (marked by the mouse cursor in the screenshot) is selected, the new project silently opens in the same window, replacing the currently opened project. The *Attach Project* command appears in the *File* menu.
- If the *Confirm window to open project in option* is selected, PyCharm prompts you to select whether you want to open the project in a new window, reuse the existing window, or attach the new project to the currently opened project. The project that has already been opened is the primary project.

*System Settings* is highlighted in blue in this screenshot. This page is accessed by in PyCharm by *File* -> *Settings* -> *System Settings*.

[image: PyCharm Settings]

Comment: I found it moments after posting using `ctrl+shift+A`. This IDE is so well done. I hate that we all grew up using painful help menus.